# MariaDB upgrade fails with "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to upgrade MariaDB 10.2 to 10.4 and it goes smooth up to phase 4/7:

```
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 437: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

How to allow longer key length?

Comment: Line number doesn't show exactly the table.

Comment: Do you have some long database/table/column/etc names?